# what is the default ownership permission of /var directory?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, directory, ownership

I just messed up with my /var permissions , setting the chmod -R 775 and chown $USER:USER to it.. My poblem is, i want to set its default permission.

Is there someone who can help me on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Owner User and Group of my **/var** folder is root/root (permission 755).
This is my output of: `ls -d /var/`

```
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Apr 16  2014 /var/
```

Comment: @florentinefrancisco if he answered your question, please remember to accept or up vote his answer.